# How may I define the pressures of two sides of a membrane in Materials Studio?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, water, membranes, materials-studio

To study SiO2, polyamide and two-layer SiO2-polyamide as the membranes in the reverse osmosis desalination of saline water; I used the Materials Studio software to model the systems. My question is:

**How can the pressures of two sides of the membrane be defined in the software?**

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned (the OP has not returned since posting the question). If the OP returns and the question is still of interest, I can reopen it.

Comment: Sure, and when they do, the pressure difference can be calculated via knowledge of the difference in chemical potentials, amongst other methods. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_pressure